# Reasonably how much free space should one leave for best performance?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, storage, internal-sd

(Reasonably because freeing space brings diminishing returns, correct or no?)

## Background

I'm testing different SD card schedulers to get the best performance. I'm assuming that when I will have more free space and use the best governor for that situation the performance should be better than now with the best governor for now's situation.

## Question

I want to find out if I can somehow find out the best scheduler and read ahead combination without having to test every combination.

So is there some way to calculate/find this? If not then what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO these governor settings are overrated. Of course it's nice to have such options, but it's confusing users more instead of helping them.

Just check your ROM and ask other users for their opinions. In AOKP for example you only need NOOP and Interactive and you should be good to go for anything.

You should save your time for more important things in Android. Just my advice, though.

Comment: Thanks.Your advice is good.I've done the more important tweaks already and sdcard is next on my list.Do you mean users as people who might answer my question?Improvement of sdcard performance is useful even if it might confuse you how to do it. **Can you however answer my space question?**

Comment: Sir, what are you talking about!? Since when does one use a scheduler for an SD card?? What is "useful" here in your opinion?? Buy a fast SD card (SDHC, class 10 alike), everything else is nonsense.

Comment: Sir, please look here about a few schedulers. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1558153 Whatever SDcard I will have a scheduler should improve the sdcard's performance unless I already had the best one enabled.

Comment: No, no. These schedulers are for CPU I/O only. Your SD card is not affected by these settings. Correct me please, if I am wrong. What you could do, for whatever reason, is to experiment with the read-ahead value. But you won't need these strange apps, that is what I meant with nonsense. You just can not "overclock" your SD card. Go with a good manufacturer, look for quality. What they use on their chips is good and should be preferred.

Comment: At least in theory the sdcard is affected by what scheduler it is managed by.I will soon find out if fact stands up to theory.However I want to find out if I can somehow find out the best scheduler and read ahead combination without having to test every combination.

Comment: I would recommend optimizing your device for your preferred scheduler and governor (use user experiences for your device), and after that testing read-ahead ideas. All above 2048KB won't affect anything and I read also that this "theory" and its difference (if any) is not as significant as if you let your SD card just be. Also keep in mind that you could damage your SD card. So make backups before playing with these values.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the governor has such a small effect and the default governor is mostly the best. The only thing you could do to improve performance is to overclock your phone which will come with heat issues though.

Depending on how many apps you have installed (and use regularly) and how much RAM you have, you should have 500-2000 MB of free storage to prevent apps from crashing and losing data (such as WhatsApp) or extreme lag. Low-end devices with little RAM tend to have bigger problems, and leaving them with less than 500 MB is a disaster.

Apps are using cache so that they don't have to load certain files over and over again on boot and use less RAM. If there is no place for cache, the app will crash or try using more RAM and crash then if there is none available.

You can use apps such as CCleaner to free space (I just used it again after decades and cleaned up 9GB (7GB thumbnails, 700MB app cache, 1,5GB useless downloads, mostly apps).

If you are low on RAM and memory, you need to clear the cache regularly or you will encounter lag and bad performance.